# Communicate with MySQL database using ASP.net

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, actionscript-3

I am building flash web based application using as3 and I want to receive and send data to MySQL server. I found out that I cannot communicate directly with MySQL from as3 and I have to use a PHP script. So I am trying to find a way to communicate with database with asp.net solution instead of PHP. thanks

Comment: **I cannot communicate directly with MySQL and I have to use a PHP script.** why?

Comment: Who said you can't use MySql with ASP.net ... see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515911/how-to-use-mysql-with-asp-net) for more details

Comment: Flash is a client-side thing, if you need it to get data from MySQL server you need to make AJAX call to server-side code, which can be anything - PHP, ASP.NET, etc.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Sir can you please give me some web site links

Comment: For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045986/flash-ajax-call, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634808/php-send-var-to-as3-with-ajax-or-post or just google "AS3 AJAX"

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I read your link but the problem is I need a asp.net solution not PHP. Because I am using asp.net web application. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't matter - client side (Flash/AS3) stays the same. You just read data in your ASP.NET page via MySQL provider and send it to the client either as XML or JSON. Again Google "ADO.NET MySQL" and "DataTable XML JSON"